# I am looking for a terminal command that not only list all of the installed applications but, also has a breif discription of each one

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I tried

```
apt list --installed
```

That did give me a long list of all of the applications, but without a description I don't know what I am looking at, so, I don't know what to ignore for now and which to research.

I also tried

```
apt list --installed | wc
```

but, I got the error code apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
After looking over apt in the man pages it appears I cant pipe those command together for some reason.
I also tried combinations of `apt`, `list`, `--installed` with `apt-cache`
but, I failed. I know I am far from skilled, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: did you look at the results of `dpkg -l` ?   (*it's results can be routed to a file if necessary/useful; though as you gave no OS & release details my quick test was on my release*)

Comment: Why would you want a machine-generated list of 10,000-or-so unorganized package descriptions? (One hopes you're not going to *print* it!)

Comment: Aha, this is an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The actual problem is determining which packages to include/exclude from your remix. You have decided that listing all the packages and their descriptions is your preferred solution. There are better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

`apt list --installed --verbose`

Answer (score 2):

To list installed packages and a brief description,

Run:

```
aptitude search '~i'
```

This displays nicely if you set your terminal size to 24 X 132

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the results of `dpkg -l` ?

It's results can be routed to a file if necessary/useful; though as you gave no OS & release details my quick test was on my release*

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   dpkg -l >blah
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   view blah

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold                                                                                                                                                     
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend                                                                                                                
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)                                                                                                                                    
||/ Name                                          Version                                     Architecture Description                                                                        
+++-=============================================-===========================================-============-==================================================================================>
ii  2048-qt                                       0.1.6-2build1                               amd64        mathematics based puzzle game                                                      
ii  a11y-profile-manager-indicator                0.1.11-0ubuntu4                             amd64        Accessibility Profile Manager - Unity desktop indicator                            
ii  abe                                           1.1+dfsg-4                                  amd64        side-scrolling game named "Abe's Amazing Adventure"                                
ii  abe-data                                      1.1+dfsg-4                                  all          side-scrolling game named "Abe's Amazing Adventure" -- data                        
ii  accountsservice                               0.6.55-3ubuntu2                             amd64        query and manipulate user account information                                      
ii  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas                0.0.7+21.10.20210712-0ubuntu1               all          AccountsService schemas for Ubuntu                                                 
ii  acl                                           2.2.53-10ubuntu2                            amd64        access control list - utilities                                                    
ii  acpi-support                                  0.143build1                                 amd64        scripts for handling many ACPI events
```

etc

Comment: It still contains a load of detail that is likely unwanted if you're wanting this for scripting purposes, but it's a start (*though only one possible way*)

Comment: I am attempting to learn more by using cubic to build a custom distro.I downloaded ubuntu-20. Cubic sent "important" apps over. I am  
looking for a description of each  just long enough so I can categorize them into low level programs, and higher level programs that I can research and decide if
I want to remove them. Ex there are several apps that start with firefox,  I might only want TOR. Many are only 3 letters. I don't want to have to 
research all of them tonight.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 is a very different system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  There is no `dpkg` or `apt` available in the *year* or 20 products, as the *year* format has been used by Ubuntu to represent *snap* only products of Ubuntu since 2016.  ie. Ubuntu Core 20 is not the same as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Sorry for the mix up the comments have a character limit ,so I cut some info. I put  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS into cubic. Thanks everybody who mentioned dpkg -l. I did try it before posting didn't work for me. But.... After reading your post I tried it again and I saw the emulator window was blocking the description. So, now I am halfway there. I am now working on how to modify the command to only show me what is to be installed, and to show me all of the pages.

Comment: The `dpkg -l >blah` put into the file `blah` all my installed packages (`dpkg` is a command that works on packages, not apps)... I only copied part of the `view` output as it's thousands of lines long for my system; you didn't provide release details, but output was only installed packages for my release.

Comment: If you don't want the additional information provided by `dpkg -l`, then you could use `dpkg-query` directly - it provides more flexibility regarding field selection and formating ex. `dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package;-50}${binary:Summary}\n'`

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all commands on the system with man pages using

```
man -s 1,6,8 -k .
```

Section 1 is user commands, section 6 is games, section 8 is admin commands.